# DataTable alphabet search affects all tables

Tags: datatables

I have integrated the alphabet search on one of my tables but it is affecting all of the tables, and I have many in different tabs of my view.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
 var _alphabetSearch = '';
var alphabet;
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, searchData) {
    if (!_alphabetSearch) {
        return true;
    }
    if (searchData[1].charAt(0) === _alphabetSearch) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

 $(document).ready(function () {
    //debugger;
    alphabet = $('<div style="font-size:x-small" class="alphabet"/>').append('Search: ');
    $('<span class="clear active"/>')
        .data('letter', '')
        .html('None')
        .appendTo(alphabet);
    for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
        $('<span/>')
            .data('letter', letter)
            .html(letter)
            .appendTo(alphabet);
    }

 var table = $("#tblAllUsers").DataTable();
    alphabet.insertBefore(table.table().container());
    alphabet.on('click', 'span', function () {
        var tst = alphabet.find('.active');
        alphabet.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        var t = $(this);
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var let = $(this).data('letter');
        _alphabetSearch = $(this).data('letter');
        table.draw();
    });
```

Initialize table now with this:

```
 $("#tblProviders").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetProvidersById")?id=' + $("#txtid").val(),
        bJQueryUI: true,
        sProcessing: "<img src='~/Images/spinner.gif' />",
        dom: 'AT<"clear">rtip',
        "pageLength": 5,
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "oLanguage": {
            sEmptyTable: "There are no Providers at this time",
            sZeroRecords: "There are no Providers at this time"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "10%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "10%", sClass: "smallfonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            {
                "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "centerbutton", "sName": "UserId", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {

                    return "<button type='button' class='displaybutton' id='" + row[0] + "' onclick=RemoveProvider(this);return false; >Remove</button>";
                }
            }
        ],
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [

            ]

        }
    });
    $("#tblProviders").dataTable().fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
    otab = $("#tblProviders").dataTable();
    otab.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]);
```

I've now included the newest files for the alpha search from the website and the alpha line shows up but each letter has zero results.

Answer (score 1):

You're implementing alphabetical search as described in [part I of this article](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-08-26). This article had also [final part](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-09-22) that had code supporting multiple tables.

All you need to do is to include `dataTables.alphabetSearch.css` and `dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js`, that can be downloaded on [features plug-ins page](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/features/) and use the code below:

```
var table = $('#tblAllUsers').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Alfrtip'
} );
```

We have enhanced alphabetical search plug-in adding search support, row grouping, number filtering, localization and alternative sorting mechanism, see [jQuery DataTables - Alphabetical search](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-alphabetical-search/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: So with the new files do I exclude the function extension call I made and the setting up of the alpha click function?

Comment: @Dean.DePue, correct. All that code will be in the plug-in files, all you need is to include them and define `dom` option with `A` letter.

Comment: I included in my main view and the alpha line shows up but every letter shows zero results.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've added code to the question - alpha shows up but all with no results.

Comment: @Dean.DePue, If you're using jQuery DataTables 1.9.x version, alphabet plugin is not compatible with that version. You need to upgrade to jQuery DataTables 1.10.

Comment: I am using 1.10.10, at least that is what is listed in the header of the file: jquery.dataTables.js

Comment: @Dean.DePue, do you have the data to alphabetize in the first column? That is the column used for alphabetical search.

Comment: I set the column to search as 1 which contains the name.  The actual first column, column 0, is the ID, which I hide or make not visible.  I added the alphabetSearch column designator for column 1 but it does not work.  I tried every column and none of them worked.

Comment: I even downloaded and included dataTables.min.js from your site which is 1.10.11 and that made no difference.

Comment: @Dean.DePue, my version differs because it has column designator. The version from DataTables website requires names to be in the first column with index `0`.

Comment: OK, so I switched column 0 and 1 and made 1 invisible.  The filtering works now but the number displayed below each alpha character is till zero.  I achieved this also by changing your file in line 52 from this if ( searchData[0].charAt(0) === context.alphabetSearch ) { to if ( searchData[1].charAt(0) === context.alphabetSearch ) { and the search worked but the numbers did not.  So no go no matter what I do.

Comment: In the draw function this line var columnData = table.column(0).data(); always returns a zero length.

Comment: Ultimately I commented out the helper match-count for mouse enter so the zeros would not show.